# Using IvyDE with different workspaces on different branches

Tags: java, eclipse, caching, branch, ivy

I am having problems using IvyDE when I have different workspaces for different branches.  I have "Resolve dependencies in workspace" switched on.  But everytime I change to a different workspace I have to remember to manually clean the caches out.  This is because IvyDE always uses the default cache for resolving dependencies within a workspace, so when switching between workspaces the cache can be polluted by different versions.

It would seem that it is impossible to work with two different workspaces at the same time.

I cannot find a way to configure the location that IvyDE uses to cache the project dependencies.  It does not appear to use the caches defined in the ivysettings.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have now got a configuration that the latest version of IvyDE is using correctly.

In my ivysettings.xml I have included the line

```
<properties file="./revision.properties" />
```

This sets the property **revision.version** that is used by our headless build scripts.

I then set the following property

```
<property name="ivy.build.cache" value="${ivy.default.ivy.user.dir}/cache/${revision.version}" override="false" />
```

The default cache used by ivyDE is then set with the following configuration block

```
<caches defaultCacheDir="${ivy.build.cache}">
    <cache name="cache" basedir="${ivy.build.cache}" />
</caches>
```

Then any resolvers need to have this cache explicitly set as in:

```
<filesystem name="build" cache="cache" latest="latest-revision">
```

This doesn't help if you have multiple workspaces on the same branch.  But it does mean that you can work on different branches at the same time without problems.